# JSON.parse returns an array, but cannot be used as an array

Tags: javascript, json

Consider the following situation:

```js
const JSONString = `["a", "b"]`;
console.log(JSON.parse(JSONString).push("c")); //returns 3 (length)
```

> Why does `JSON.parse` return the array and allows `Array` methods on it, but when you actually try to `push` something in the array it returns the length?

If we do the following it will work:

```js
const JSONString = `["a", "b"]`;
console.log(JSON.parse(JSONString).concat("c"));
```

---

Here above is the original question and answered correctly below by Quentin.
Performance question:

Would would be preferable in the situation above: `concat` or `push`, where `concat` is only one line but returns a new array. `push` needs more lines of code, but keeps the original array?

Comment: `.push()` modifies the original array and returns the array's updated length; `.concat()` does _not_ modify the original and instead returns a new array. If you use `.push()` you will have to do `const arr = JSON.parse(str); arr.push("c"); console.log(arr)`

Comment: You have 2 different array methods and you're asking why they're different?

Comment: This is working as expected, .push mutates the array and returns the new length.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does JSON.parse return the array

Because it is an array

> allows Array methods on it

Because it is an array

> when you actually try to push something in the array it returns the length?

Because the return value of the `push` function is the length of the array

To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

JSON.parse is irrelevant to this:

```js
const array = ["a", "b"];
const return_value = array.push("c");
console.log({ array, return_value });
```

---

> Would would be preferable in the situation above: concat or push, where concat is only one line but returns a new array. push needs more lines of code, but keeps the original array?

If you need the original array then the answer is obvious.

If you don't, then it is a matter of opinion.

Comment: thanks, should've figured that out on my own though. But sometimes somebody's insight is helpful. However, maybe we can expand on this and use your knowledge to full. See edit on my question.

Comment: You're quick buddy!, look again.

Comment: @Mouser - they are 2 different methods so you would use whichever you need.. `push` just adds a single element, while `concat` could add another array...

Comment: @tymeJV You can push multiple elements by a single `push` call.